# SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, amazon-redshift

Following `insert statement` and entire application backed with `redshift` was working before I have changed redshift nodes. 
I just have changed redshift nodes from 4 to 2. 
Now, I am getting following error while connecting my `Postgres` server through `CodeIgniter`

```
Error Number:

SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected

INSERT INTO "ci_sessions" ("session_id", "ip_address", "user_agent", "last_activity",    "user_data") VALUES ('8aa51cba3c035aac1c2a3f8e43651b6b', '182.237.148.0', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11;  Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0', 1419056314, '')

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 328
```

Comment: So what was working? What output do you expect? Your question is not clear.

Comment: application was working (or you can say this particular insert statement),
which uses `codeigniter` `php framework` to connect to `amazon-redshift`

Comment: This error could come from many places : postgresql, redshift, redshift network access, redshift certificate, your network access, your SSL configuration in the server configuration, php configuration, your proxy configuration, even a lack of memory could lead to an exception somewhere. If you wish us to help you, you have to give more details on all those intermediaries. Start with your SSL library used within PHP and your server configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Amazon Redshift, but I did have this error long time ago due to connection loss, so I added 'tcpKeepAlive' Parameter to the connection string and it works :

```
jdbc:postgresql://myhost.dev/?tcpKeepAlive=true
```

Answer (score 0):

From Amazon Redshift [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyCluster.html):

> When you submit your request to resize a cluster, Amazon Redshift sets
>   access permissions for the cluster to read-only. After Amazon Redshift
>   provisions a new cluster according to your resize requirements, there
>   will be a temporary outage while the old cluster is deleted and your
>   connection is switched to the new cluster. When the new connection is
>   complete, the original access permissions for the cluster are
>   restored. You can use DescribeResize to track the progress of the
>   resize request.

You don't say how much time you are experiencing this problem, but according to amazon, you cannot connect temporarily to your cluster due to permission/connectivity issues. Eventually the connection will be restored.

Comment: thanks for reaching out, but as you think connection will eventually restored is not true.
As I can connect to `redshift` from other sources other than `CI App`, and problem will only solved after restarting server.
For live application, server restart is not possible every time.

Comment: @SandipPingle hmm, have you checked if the node runs out of memory at all?

Comment: as I mentioned, I can connect redshift from other `PHP` script as well as trough `Postgresql client`.
Hence I don't think node runs out of memory.